# problem deploying ruby on rails app to Heroku: ruby version issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku-postgres

I forked and cloned a repo so I could deploy to Heroku - then I got the message below asking to upgrade the project Ruby version.

!     The Ruby version you are trying to install does not exist on this stack.
!
!     You are trying to install ruby-2.7.4 on heroku-22.
!
!     Ruby ruby-2.7.4 is present on the following stacks:
!
!     - heroku-18
!     - heroku-20
!
!     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
!     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
!
!     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
!     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
!
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
!     Push failed

In my Mac when I run ruby -v  I get 3.1.2 version. When I go into the project's Gemfile and type the old version to the latest, I run bundle install but I get this message:

rbenv: version `2.7.4' is not installed (set by /Users/luciamoral/code/Luciamoral/Driven-App/.ruby-version)

Does this mean I need to also install the oldest version so it works? Also, I found that it is not recording changes when I push to origin master, despite having forked and cloned it to my machine. Any ideas please? Thanks!

Comment: Did `bundle` say something like `Your Ruby version is 3.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.4`?

Answer (score 0):

You have the Ruby version specified in two places, `.ruby-version` and `Gemfile`. Only use one. Heroku only cares about the `Gemfile`.

Your options are to either downgrade to a version of the heroku stack which supports your version of Ruby, which just pushes off the problem, or upgrade your Ruby version.

Comment: thanks a lot Schwern, I have upgraded to latest version and successfully deployed to Heroku. Now I need to debug.